# Camera doesn't works in phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

i am integrating camera in my phonegap application to record a video and to capture an image. i am using Phonegap 1.5.0 for iPhone.

to capture an imge i am using this code:

```
  function capturePhoto() { 

   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, fail, { quality: 30 }); 
   }
```

On button click i am calling above function but it did nothing.
can anybody help me in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried it with Cordova latest and it's working fine. Please check the code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {

console.log("CORDOVA IS WORKING:::");
}

        function capturePhoto()
{
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, is it possible to embed camera to div in ios phonegap?